# How to deduce R from a set of sentences that I have?

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus, natural-deduction

I can't figure out how to deduce $R$ from the set of sentences $\{R \leftrightarrow ((P \to (Q \land \lnot R)) \lor P), \, P, \, \lnot R \to Q\}$.

Any tips ? I am really bad with deductions.
So far I have:

1. $P \ $       Premise
2. $\lnot R \to Q \ $ Premise
3. $R \to ((P \to (Q \land \lnot R) \lor P)) \ $ Premise
4. $\lnot R \ $  Premise
5. $\lnot\lnot R \ $ Premise
6. $R \ $  (4,5 RAA)
7. $P \to (Q \land \lnot R) \lor P \ $ (MP 3,6)

Comment: Exactly what rules do you have? There are many different rule sets ...

Comment: You've missed a premise, or misrepresented a premise.  $(3)$ should be $R \leftrightarrow ((P \to (Q \land \lnot R))\lor P).$  That means:  $$\Big(R \to ((P \to (Q \land \lnot R))\lor P) \Big) \land \big(((P \to (Q \land \lnot R))\lor P)\to R\Big)$$   You forgot one side

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is quite easy, if you consider $A \leftrightarrow B$ as a shorthand for $(A \to B) \land (B \to A)$:

1. $P \ $ Premise
2. $R \leftrightarrow ((P \to (Q \land \lnot R)) \lor P) \ $ Premise
3. $((P \to (Q \land \lnot R)) \lor P) \to R \ $ Simplification (conjunction elimination) from 2
4. $(P \to (Q \land \lnot R)) \lor P \ $ Addition (disjunction introduction) from 1
5. $R \ $ Modus ponens from 3 and 4.

Comment: Wow so simple! Totally failed to see that. You save my life! I did manage to prove it but in 10 lines instead of 5 haha.

Answer (score 0):

Since $R \leftrightarrow ((P \to (Q \wedge \neg R)) \vee P)$, in order to prove $R$, it suffices to prove $(P \to (Q \wedge \neg R)) \vee P$. But this is a disjunction, so it suffices either to prove $P \to (Q \wedge \neg R)$ or to prove $P$. Can you take it from here?

Answer (score 0):

Hint $$\begin{array}{|l}(S\vee P)\to R\\P\\\hline S\vee P\hspace{10ex} \vee\mathsf I\\R\hspace{14ex}\to\mathsf E\end{array}$$